# Filtering data ordered by rowversion

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning

I have a SQL table of data with the following structure :

```sql
CREATE TABLE Data(
    Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    Date datetime NOT NULL,
    Value decimal(20, 10) NULL,
    RV timestamp NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Data PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id, Date)
)
```

The number of distinct Ids ranges from 3000 to 50000.
The size of the table varies up to over a billion rows.
One Id can cover between a few rows up to 5% of the table.

The single most executed query on this table is :

```sql
SELECT Id, Date, Value, RV
FROM Data
WHERE Id = @Id
AND Date Between @StartDate AND @StopDate
```

---

I now have to implement incremental retrieval of data on a subset of Ids, including updates.
I then used a request scheme in which the caller provide a specific rowversion, retrieve a block of data and use the maximum rowversion value of the returned data for the subsequent call.

I have written this procedure  :

```sql
CREATE TYPE guid_list_tbltype AS TABLE (Id uniqueidentifier not null primary key)
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
    @Ids guid_list_tbltype READONLY,
    @Cursor rowversion,
    @MaxRows int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT A.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            Data.Id,
            Date,
            Value,
            RV,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RV) AS RN
        FROM Data
             inner join (SELECT Id FROM @Ids) Ids ON Ids.Id = Data.Id
        WHERE RV > @Cursor
    ) A 
    WHERE RN <= @MaxRows
END
```

Where `@MaxRows` will range between 500,000 and 2,000,000 depending on how chunked the client will want his data.

---

I have tried different approaches :

1. Indexing on (Id, RV) :

```sql
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_IDRV ON Data(Id, RV) INCLUDE(Date, Value);
```

Using the index, the query seek the rows where `RV = @Cursor` for each `Id` in `@Ids`, read the following rows then merge the result and sort.
 Efficiency then depends on the relative position of `@Cursor` value.
If it is close to the end of data (ordered by RV) the query is instantaneous and if not the query can take up to minutes (never let it run to the end).

the problem with this approach is that `@Cursor` is either near the end of data and the sort isn't painful (not even needed if the query return less rows than `@MaxRows`) either it is further behind and the query has to sort `@MaxRows * LEN(@Ids)` rows.

1. Indexing on RV :

```sql
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_RV ON Data(RV) INCLUDE(Id, Date, Value);
```

Using the index, the query seek the row where `RV = @Cursor` then read every row discarding the non-requested Ids until it reaches `@MaxRows`.
 Efficiency then depends on the % of requested Ids (`LEN(@Ids) / COUNT(DISTINCT Id)`) and their distribution.
 More requested Id % means less discarded rows which means more efficient reads, less requested Id % means more discarded rows which means more reads for the same amount of resulting rows.

The problem with this approach is that if the requested Ids contains only a few elements, it might have to read the whole index to get the desired rows.

1. Using Filtered index or indexed views

```sql
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_RVClient1 ON Data(Id, RV) INCLUDE(Date, Value)
    WHERE Id IN (/* list of Ids for specific client*/);
```

Or

```sql
    CREATE VIEW vDataClient1 WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    SELECT
        Id,
        Date,
        Value,
        RV
    FROM dbo.Data
    WHERE Id IN (/* list of Ids for specific client*/)
```

```sql
    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_IDRV ON vDataClient1(Id, Rv);
```

This method allows for perfectly efficient indexing and query execution plans but come with disadvantages : 
  1. Practically, I will have to implement dynamic SQL to create the indexes or views and  modify the requesting procedure to use the right index or view.
  2. I will have to maintain one index or view by existing client, including storage.
  3. Every time a client will have to modify his list of requested Ids, I will have to drop the index or view and recreate it.

---

I can't seem to find a method that will suit my needs.
I'm looking for better ideas to implement incremental data retrieval.
Those ideas could imply reworking the requesting scheme or the database schema although I'd prefer a better indexing approach if there is one.

Comment: Crosspost with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586004/filtering-data-ordered-by-rowversion. I've removed Oracle version for the moment because I've discovered that ORA_ROWSCN isn't indexable (and hardly through indexed materialized views).

Comment: How does the date field fit in? Can a row with a particular ID and Date be updated in the table? And if so, is the date also updated (like an additional timestamp?)

Comment: Seems like for GetData() attempt, the order by should include the Id (order by RV, Id).  Can you comment on using an index of (Rv, Id)?  Also using ">" max rowversion from previous call seems like it will miss records between chunks if rows have the same rowversion (isn't that possible?).

Comment: @8kb : the update statements that run on the table only modify the `Value` column.
@crokusek : Won't ordering by RV, ID instead of RV only increase sort workload without any benefice, I don't understand the reasoning behind your comment.
From what I've read, RV should be unique unless inserting data specifically into that column, which the application does not.

Comment: Can the client accept results in (Id, Rv) order and  provide a LastId argument in addition to LastRowVersion argument to eliminate RV sort across ids?  My previous comments were all based on the assumption that RV had duplicates. The filtered index per client looked interesting.

Comment: If you sort the result by (Id, RV), even providing the last Id and last RV for the next call will make it miss many rows. The only way to make it work using a (Id, RV) sort is force the client to track RV at the Id level, and not at the global level (which might be one solution).

Comment: For the (Id, RV) order not to lose rows, one could calc a min(RV) and max(RV) across a client's Ids whenever the Id's rollover and pass the range back to client as part of state. The client would then pass LastId, LastIdRv, MinRv, MaxRv with each call. The min/max calc should be fast with the (Id, RV) index but sensing the rollover and combining rows for the lastId with the firstId++ within the requested number of rows might require a temp table or maybe a recursive union if that's possible. I don't think the client could seed the search if they lost the min/max values mid-batch.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is for the client application to remember the maximum `rowversion` per ID.  The user-defined table type would change to:

```
CREATE TYPE
    dbo.guid_list_tbltype
AS TABLE 
    (
    Id      uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY, 
    LastRV  rowversion NOT NULL
    );
```

The query in the procedure can then be rewritten to use the `APPLY` pattern (see my SQLServerCentral articles [part 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/) and [part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/) - free login required).  The key to good performance here is the `ORDER BY` - it avoids *unordered* pre-fetching on the nested loops join.  The `RECOMPILE` is necessary to allow the optimizer to see the cardinality of the table variable at compilation time (probably resulting in a desirable parallel plan).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetData

    @IDs        guid_list_tbltype READONLY,
    @MaxRows    bigint

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP (@MaxRows)
        d.Id,
        d.[Date],
        d.Value,
        d.RV
    FROM @Ids AS i
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            d.*
        FROM dbo.Data AS d
        WHERE
            d.Id = i.Id
            AND d.RV > i.LastRV
    ) AS d
    ORDER BY
        i.Id,
        d.RV
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);

END;
```

You should get a *post-execution* query plan like this (estimated plan will be serial):

[image: query plan]

Comment: Right, one of the design change solution is to have the client remember the `MAX(RV)` per Id (or a subscription system where the internal application remembers all Id/RV pairs) and I use this patern for an other client. An other solution was to force the client to always retrieve all the Ids (which make the indexing problem trivial). It still doesn't cover the question particular need : Incremental retrieval of a subset of Ids with only one global counter provided by the client.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I would redesign the table. If we can have VersionNumber as an incremental integer with no gaps, that the task of retrieving the next chunk is a totally trivial range scan. All we need is the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_IDRV ON Data(Id, VersionNumber) INCLUDE(Date, Value);
```

Of course, we need to make sure that VersionNumber starts with one and has no gaps. This is [easy to do with constraints.](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/yet-another-sql-strategy-for-versioned-data/)

Comment: Do you mean a global or an Id local `VersionNumber` ? Either case, I'm unable to see how that will help with the question, could you elaborate further ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would have done:

In this instance, your PK should be a "Surrogate Key" Identity Field that auto-increments.
Since you're already in the billions, it would be best to go with a BigInt.
Let's call it **DataID**.
This will:

- Add 8 Bytes to every record in your Clustered Index.
- Save 16 Bytes on
  every record in every Non-Clustered Index.
- What you had was a "Natural Key": a UniqueIdentifyer (16 Bytes) w/ a DateTime (8 Bytes).
- That's 24 Bytes in every Index Record to reference back to the Clustered Index!
- This is why we have Surrogate Keys as Smaller Incrementing Integers.

Set your new BigInt PK (**DataID**) to use a Clustered-Index:
This will:

- Ensure the most recently created records are placed near the end.
- Allow for faster Indexing with other Non-Clustered Indexes.
- Allow for future expansion as an FK to other Tables.

Create a Non-Clustered-Index around (Date,Id).
This will:

- Speed up your most commonly used queries.
- You could add "Value", but it will increase the size of your index, which makes it slower.
- I'd suggest trying it in and outside of the Index to see if there is a vast difference in performance.
- I'd recommend not to use "Include" if you do add it.
- Just tack in on like so (Date,Id,Value) - but *only* if your testing shows it improves performance.

Create a Non-Clustered Index on (RV,ID).
This will:

- Always keep your Indexes as small as possible.
- Unless you notice crazy-huge performance gains with having the Date and Value in your Indexes, I'd suggest you leave them out to conserve disk space.  Give it a try without them first.
- If you do add Date or Value, do not use "Include", instead add them to the ordering of the Index.
- Thanks to the DataID Incrementing on new Inserts into your Clustered PK, your recent RV's will usually appear near the end (unless you're updating swaths of data from the past all the time).